# Copying selected property values of one object to another

Tags: javascript, object, copy

I have 2 javascript objects: obj_a and obj_b:

```
var obj_a = {'p1':{x:100, y:200, z:100}, 'p2':{x:100, y:100, z:300}};
var obj_b = {'p1':{x:100, y:200}, 'p2':{x:100, y:100}};
```

I'm trying to copy only "x and y values" of obj_b to obj_a if they're different.
For example,

if `obj_b = {'p1':{x:200, y:200}, 'p2':{x:300, y:400}};`,

final obj_a will be `obj_a = {'p1':{x:200, y:200, z:100}, 'p2':{x:300, y:400, z:300}};`. completely ignoring the property "z" of obj_a.

So, I've written the following:

```
function isDifferent(a, b) {
    var aProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a);
    var bProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b);
    for (var i = 0; i < bProps.length; i++) {
        var propName = bProps[i];
         if (a[propName] != b[propName]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
for (var prop in obj_b){
    if(isDifferent(obj_a[prop], obj_b[prop]){
        var bProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj_b[prop]);
        for (var i = 0; i < bProps.length; i++){
            var propName = bProps[i];
            obj_a[prop].propName = obj_b[prop].propName;
        }
    }
}
```

But there's a problem in copying using obj_a[prop].propName since I only get undefined when I `console.log(obj_a[prop].propName);`. When I tried `console.log(obj_a[p1].x);`, the output is the old value: "200". Can somebody enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `obj_a[prop][propName]`.
`object[prop].propName` is the same as `object[prop]["propName"]` which means that it'll search for the property whose name is "propName" **literally**.

Therefore, `obj_a[p1].x` will return the value that you expect but `obj_a[p1].propName` will be undefined since your obj_a[p1] doesn't have a property name "propName".

What you want is to treat "propName" as a "string variable" not as a "string literal".

Answer (score 3):

If you're referencing an object property by a name stored in a variable, you need to use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). In your case, instead of

```
var propName = bProps[i];
obj_a[prop].propName = obj_b[prop].propName;
```

use

```
var propName = bProps[i];
obj_a[prop][propName] = obj_b[prop][propName];
```